# How can I change starting activity in Basic4Android?

Tags: basic4android

Is there a way to change starting activity in Basic4Android?

Always Main activity automatic added and set the starting activity.

Program not let to change its name too...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: "Project" -> "Manifest Editor" and a popup window with Android manifest xml code will show up. Insert this code after `AddManifestText(...` and change `yourActivityName` to what you want.

```
 <activity android:name=".yourActivityName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You can run `Activity.Title= "YourTitle"` in any activity to display alternative name in the title bar if that is why you are looking to change the startup activity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, I think it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch names of two activities in the manifest editor which would effectively start your app from activity2 code module:

```
SetActivityAttribute(Main, android:name, ".activity2")
SetActivityAttribute(Activity2, android:name, ".main")
```